# Why the object I didn't manipulate changed in Java?

Tags: java, list, pointers, object

When I was trying to apply GA algorithm, I found a problem: I copy the value of a list A to another B, and I  manipulated B. But when I was running the unit test. I simply found both the values of A and B changed. And I have no idea what happened.
Below is my code:

```
public class GA_bags {
    private Population population;
    private int fittest;
    private List<Individual> offsprings;

public GA_bags(int n,int sumBags,int maxWeight,Bag[] bags){
    this.population=new Population(n,sumBags,maxWeight,bags);
}


//Crossover Function
public void crossover(){
    Random random=new Random();
    List<Individual> individuals=population.getIndividuals();
    offsprings=new ArrayList<>(individuals);    //Intialize the offsprings, simply copy first
    int pos=random.nextInt(offsprings.get(0).getGenes().length);    //decide the position of genes to crossover
    for(int i=0;i<offsprings.size()-1;i+=2){         //1st fittest pair with 2nd fittest,3nd with the 4th...
        for(int j=0;j<=pos;j++){
            int tem=offsprings.get(i).getGenes()[j];
            offsprings.get(i).getGenes()[j]=offsprings.get(i+1).getGenes()[j];
            offsprings.get(i+1).getGenes()[j]=tem;
        }
    }
}
```

After I implement the crossover method, both List individuals and offsprings changed, but I only manipulated the List offsprings.

```
public class Individual {
//each individual is a solution of KnapsackProblem
private int[] genes;      //"1" stands for the bag is chosen, while "0" stands for the bag is not
private Bag[] bags;       //each digit of gene is responsible for a specific Bag object
private int fitness;     //the fitness of an individual
private int curWeight;   //the weight of this individual
private int maxWeight;   //once the total weight of bags of this individual over maxWeight, then fitness is 0

public Individual(int sumBags,int maxWeight,Bag[] bags){
     this.genes=new int[sumBags];
     this.maxWeight=maxWeight;
     this.bags=bags;
     Random random=new Random();
     for(int i=0;i<sumBags;i++){
         genes[i]=random.nextInt(2);       //genetic code: random generate genes,"0" or "1"
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: `offsprings=new ArrayList<>(individuals);` is not going to create `new` `Individual` Objects - they point to the same Objects

Comment: So how should I change it?

Comment: [clone](https://dzone.com/articles/shallow-and-deep-java-cloning)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about deep copy and [here](https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-deep-clone-example-source-code) is an example.

If you want to copy a primitive type, you can just use `=`. If you want to copy an object, `=` is just make the variable point to the object address. So the both variables point to the same object.

If you want new variable points to a totally new object, you need to copy it by yourself. The simplest way is to copy the primitive attributes one by one.

Comment: I beat you by a second (as a comment as it should be)

Comment: A good answer would have a bit more substance than this and be self-contained.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi ScaryWombat , rustyx, getting your point and add some explanation.